# CakePHP HTML Helper not working with Images

Tags: cakephp

I have been developing a website in CakePHP 2.5.6 and have suddenly had an issue where when using $this->Html->Image(''); the image wont display on the page and I get this error if I go to the Image URL Directly:

```
Missing Controller
Error: ImgController could not be found.

Error: Create the class ImgController below in file: app/Controller/ImgController.php

<?php
class ImgController extends AppController {

}
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/missing_controller.ctp
```

As I haven't been using CakePHP for long im not sure where to start with resolving this, its never done this before to me.

Any help would be appreciated,
Steve

EDIT: 
The example I have been using is this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('cake.power.gif');?>
```

it returns the following:

```
<img src="/trunk/img/cake.power.gif" alt="" />
```

I have checked and the image does exist on my server in the directory app/webroot/img/cake.power.gif

Comment: Could you provide an example of the $this->Html->Image('') causing the error? Does the image exist at the path Cake is looking for it at?

Comment: @drmonkeyninja Edited post to answer your question

Comment: Are the file permissions correct for your img directory? Cake doesn't appear to be able to find the file to deliver it so is interpreting the request as a call to a controller that doesn't exist.

Comment: just changed the file permission to 777 and I still get the same result, the owner is apache.

Comment: Could you show result of `echo Configure::read('App.imageBaseUrl')));`?

Comment: The html-helper tag _ Refers to the `HtmlHelper` class for ASP.NET MVC views_. I have removed it.

Comment: @marian0 `echo Configure::read('App.imageBaseUrl');` returned: `img/`